# How to Transfer files from computer to cloud server using an intermediate server?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, rsync

I have a hardrive containing 2.5 TB of data. I want to copy these files to my cloud server which has enough hspace. But, this cloud server can only be accessed through a intermediate server, which doesn't have enough space to copy this data and then transfer it to the cloud.

I know I can do this using a ssh tunnel but I don't have administrative access for executing this. I would also want the files to be copied using rsync to perform a checksum and then transfer. Is there any way to do this without having to section the data and then transfer?

Answer (score 0):

This is doable through an intermediate SSH server (OpenSSH 7.1 or greater)

```
rsync -acz -e "ssh -o "ProxyJump <user>@<desthost>" intermediate:/path/remote /path/local
```

Or alternatively if it doesn't you can try ProxyCommand

```
rsync -acz -e "ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh <ssh opts>" intermediate:/path/remote /path/local
```

This can be simplified and tested by creating $HOME/.ssh/config entry..

```
Host intermediate
  ProxyCommand ssh <desthost>

Or:-

Host intermeiate 
 ProxyJump <desthost>
```

Thus the much simpler command:-

```
rsync -azv intermediate:/path/remote  /path/local
```